# TAR gives error - tar: You may not specify more than one `-Acdtrux' or `--test-label' option

Tags: tar

I am trying to make a tar ball and its throwing the error,

```
persis1@takwa228-DEV $ tar -pcrvzf ALPHA.tar.gz https-ALPHA

tar: You may not specify more than one `-Acdtrux' or `--test-label' option

Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the message says, you can't combine `c` and `r`; the former means "create an archive", the latter "append to an archive", so they can't be used simultaneously.

You can simply do

```
tar cpvzf ALPHA.tar.gz https-ALPHA
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me add that I ran into the same error message due to another cause. This one passed through for many months, and this morning suddenly told me

```
You may not specify more than one '-Acdtrux' or '--test-label' option
```

upon running

```
tar cfvz backup-logs.$(date +'%Y-%m-%d').tgz *.log
```

Reason was there was a file called `-crontab.log`, with a hyphen in front of the filename. Took me half an hour to figure that out. Removing the hyphen from the filename fixed that.

Comment: Preceding the filename glob with `--` on the command line  to signal the end of command line options would also have helped.

Comment: That means the filename glob is resolved and then appended to the command line? Sounds weird.